# How do I access text of Select2 when there are multiple select2 instances?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following code that works with the first selector and provides the result I am looking for, namely that results where the first to kth characters match rank above results where the characters merely exist in the option string. 
(i.e. input string "ka" would rank kansas above alaska)

It fails when run in one of the other select2 instances on the site.  Code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
userSettings.init()    
$('.select2').select2({        
    sorter: function(data) {
        return data.sort(function (a, b) {
            // Declare levenshtein algorithm
            var levenshtein = require('fast-levenshtein');

            // Trim and set to lowercase on the inputs
            a = a.text.trim().toLowerCase();
            b = b.text.trim().toLowerCase();

            /* This is the problem.  I need a better way to retrieve the
            input value in order to test it's fitness against my options. */
            var input = $('.select2-search__field').val().trim().toLowerCase();

            // Weigh by those that match the input in the beginning of the string first, and then list the rest that only contain the string next.
            if (!isUndefined(input) && input.length > 0) {
                if(input == a.substring(0, input.length))  {
                    return -1;
                } else if (input == b.substring(0, input.length))  {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    // Input doesn't match the beginning of the string, still return strings with matching characters. 
                    return levenshtein.get(a, input) - levenshtein.get(b, input);
                }
            }
        });
        // Function to ensure we are not operating on something that is undefined.
        function isUndefined(value){
            // Obtain `undefined` value that's guaranteed to not have been re-assigned.
            var undefined = void(0);
            return value === undefined;
        }
    }
})
```

});

As you can see, I need a better way to get at the input than the way I have declared var input.

**** EDIT ****

I think I have a solution.

I suspect that the sort was happening so fast, and so often, that it would just give up.  We tested this by consoling out the workflow and we would erratically lose portions of it.

As a solution, I pulled the assignment out of actual sort function and then passed it in.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    userSettings.init()    
    $('.select2').select2({sorter: s2_sorter})
});


//Function to do sort on a Select2 Field.
let s2_sorter = function(data) {

/* Obtain the value out of the text field in order to test agaist the options during sort. */
var input = {d:$('.select2-container--open .select2-search__field').val().trim().toLowerCase()};
return data.sort(function (a, b) {
    // Access the varible inside sort.
    let i = input.d;

    // Declare levenshtein algorithm
    var levenshtein = require('fast-levenshtein');

    // Trim and set to lowercase on the inputs
    a = a.text.trim().toLowerCase();
    b = b.text.trim().toLowerCase();

    // Wieght by those that match character first, and then all with the character next.
    if (!isUndefined(i) && i.length > 0) {
        console.log('hassomethign')
        if(i == a.substring(0, i.length))  {
            return -1;
        } else if (i == b.substring(0, i.length))  {
            return 1;
        } else {
            // Input doesn't match the begining of the string, still return strings with matching characters. 
            return levenshtein.get(a, i) - levenshtein.get(b, i);
        }
    }
});
function isUndefined(value){
    // Obtain `undefined` value that's guaranteed to not have been re-assigned.
    var undefined = void(0);
    return value === undefined;
}
```

};

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Would you be able to provide us with the exact error you are seeing? Please have a read through some of the [Stack overflow Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) help articles for some guidance as to what users here will expect from those asking questions. Especially the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page.

Comment: You should use `$(this).find()` to find the selection relative to the current `select2` instance.